# Weird bug when creating a user in django

Tags: python, django

I have a weird bug in django where I have 2 different profile models for each user type and one profile model creates two profile models when I create a User.

Here's my code for the user model:

```py
class User(TimeStampedModel, AbstractUser):
    class Types(models.TextChoices):
        """Default user for Side Project."""
        COMPANY = "COMPANY", "Company"
        JOB_SEEKER = "JOB SEEKER", "Job Seeker"

    base_type = Types.COMPANY

    # Type of User
    type = models.CharField(_("Type"), max_length=50, choices=Types.choices, default=base_type)
    # First and last name do not cover name patterns around the globe
    name = models.CharField(_("Name of User"), blank=True, max_length=255)
    first_name = None  # type: ignore
    last_name = None  # type: ignore


    def get_absolute_url(self) -> str:
        """Get URL for user's detail view.

        Returns:
            str: URL for user detail.

        """
        return reverse("users:detail", kwargs={"username": self.username})

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not self.id:
            self.type = self.base_type
        return super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Here's my code for the seeker profile model

```py
class SeekerProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='seeker_profile')

@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def create_or_update_seeker_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if instance.type == 'JOB SEEKER':
        SeekerProfile.objects.get_or_create(user=instance)
    elif instance.type == 'COMPANY':
        CompanyProfile.objects.get_or_create(user=instance)


@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def save_seeker_profile(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    if instance.type == 'JOB SEEKER':
        try:
            instance.seeker_profile.save()
        except SeekerProfile.DoesNotExist:
            # Handle the case where the profile doesn't exist yet
            SeekerProfile.objects.create(user=instance)
    else:
        try:
            instance.company_profile.save()
        except CompanyProfile.DoesNotExist:
            # Handle the case where the profile doesn't exist yet
            CompanyProfile.objects.create(user=instance)
```

Here's my code for the company profile model

```py
class CompanyProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='company_profile')

@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def create_or_update_company_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if instance.type == 'COMPANY':
        if created:
            CompanyProfile.objects.create(user=instance)
        else:
            try:
                instance.company_profile.save()
            except CompanyProfile.DoesNotExist:
                CompanyProfile.objects.create(user=instance)

@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def save_company_profile(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    if instance.type == 'COMPANY':
        try:
            instance.company_profile.save()
        except CompanyProfile.DoesNotExist:
            # Handle the case where the profile doesn't exist yet
            CompanyProfile.objects.create(user=instance)
```

What happens is when I create a user with a company user type, the model creates a company profile model. But when I create a seeker user type, the model creates a seeker profile model and a company profile model. What do you think I'm doing wrong? I've been going in circles with ChatGPT with this

Answer (score 0):

Both of your receivers are saving the `seeker_profile` just using different methods to check if profile exists, you only need one like so:

```
@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def create_or_update_seeker_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if instance.type == 'JOB SEEKER':
        SeekerProfile.objects.get_or_create(user=instance)
    elif instance.type == 'COMPANY':
        CompanyProfile.objects.get_or_create(user=instance)
    # other checks as needed
```

You can do as many checks as you want and it can handle all user types.

Comment: Tried this but it still creates a company profile aside from a seeker profile

Comment: As I mentioned, currently you have 4 receivers which is excessive and inefficient, you can use one to make all the checks. Implement my solution and report back please making sure you only use one signal receiver for saving/retrieving the user profiles. See edited answer

Comment: Still the same. I deleted the `signals.py` in the companies app so I have this in the seekers app 
```python
@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def save_seeker_profile(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    if instance.type == 'JOB SEEKER':
        try:
            instance.seeker_profile.save()
        except SeekerProfile.DoesNotExist:
            
            SeekerProfile.objects.create(user=instance)
    else:
        try:
            instance.company_profile.save()
        except CompanyProfile.DoesNotExist:
            CompanyProfile.objects.create(user=instance)
```

Comment: Would this be a good replacement of what I'm implementing? https://github.com/pydanny/multiple-user-types-django/blob/master/spybook/users/models.py

Comment: update your question to include your changes and the error message as that helps us have a better idea of what's going on. As for the latter, I don't know what specifically you're trying to achieve here and don't know if that's what you need.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was the default in the `type` field. Once I removed it, the bug disappeared.